# How to automate ZAP passive scan in an Android app using TestNG, Java code?

Tags: java, testng, zap

Could someone please help me by showing a sample code on how to automate passive scan in ZAP proxy tool using TestNG framework, Java for an Android app using real android device?
Pre-requests:
ZAP and Appium server to be started manually before executing the script.

Using the automation code I should be able to automatically do the passive scann in an android app.